# How to filter results with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to implement Ransack for a search feature on my website. I tried watching the Railscasts on Ransack and got a pretty good idea of how to implement it. But I am running into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

In the Index action of my Users controller, I have the following code:

```
def index
   @users = User.same_city_as(current_user)
end
```

`@users` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. `@users` is essentially capturing all the users who belong to the same city as the `current_user`. In my view I am able to iterate through `@users` and display all users belonging to the same city as the `current_user`. This is all good. Now I want to be able to filter these results based on a range of age provided by the user. Per Railcasts, I could do this:

```
def index
  @search = User.search(params[:q])
  @Users = @search.result
end
```

But then I don't have the same city scope anymore. What I want is to display all users belonging to the same city as the `current_user` by default and then filter those results by age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ransack works with **scopes**, so you can easily chain your own scopes.

Assuming `User.same_city_as` returns a scope (an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance) you can simply do this:

```
@search = User.same_city_as(current_user).search(params[:q])
@users = @search.result
```

And `@search.result` returns a scope, too, so you can apply further modifications to it, like pagination for example.

With **[Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)** this could look like:

```
@search = User.same_city_as(current_user).search(params[:q])
@users = @search.result.page(params[:page])
```

Comment: This works great. However, now I have another issue open. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849569/undefined-method-error-for-search-using-ransack-gem